# Spring JPA: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 2 superclasses, where on extends another:

**AbstractEntity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mySEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySEQ", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "VERSION_ID", nullable = false)
private Long versionId;

//getters and setters
```

}

**AbstractStringEntity:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractStringEntity extends AbstractEntity {

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Local.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION_ID", referencedColumnName = "VERSION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Collection<Local> localisedStrings = new HashSet<>();

@Transient
private transient Language language;

//gettters and setters
```

Then, I have 2 classes which extends these basics:

**Subtype:**

```
@Entity(name = "Subtype")
@Table(name = "SUBTYPE")
public class Subtype extends AbstractEntityLocalStr {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION_ID", referencedColumnName = "VERSION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Type type;


@Column(name = "ABBREVIATION")
private String abbreviation;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION_ID", referencedColumnName = "VERSION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NOTEPAD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Notepad notepad;

//getters and setters
```

**Type:**

```
@Entity(name = "Type")
@Table(name = "TYPE", uniqueConstraints =    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "HIERARCHY_LEVEL"))
public class Type extends AbstractEntity {

@Column(name = "HIERARCHY_LEVEL", unique = true)
private Integer hierarchyLevel;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION_ID", referencedColumnName = "VERSION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NOTEPAD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Notepad notepad;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "type")
private Set<Subtype> subtypes = new HashSet<>();
```

And with such mapping I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.myProj.domain.AbstractEntity.versionId to java.lang.Long
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.generateHashCode(CollectionKey.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1039) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:239) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
...
```

This mistake looks like nonsense - Long could not be cast to Long. I've tried different solutions found on stack, but they weren't useful. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Did you miss a part of your code? There's no `safetyConceptVersionId` in your `AbstractEntity` class.

Comment: @nbrooks sorry, fixed